# Nested looping for each variable in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops

I'm currently coding a discord bot that is saving economic data for it's users. The code below is expected to loop for each file saved in a folder (JSONs with the user's ID as the name of it) which contains an array of IDs of the "buildings" aka items they own.

Here is a minified JSON of the table i'm using where it will find the data for the buildings that the user owns (please note there are multiple categories and "buildings" for each category:

```
{ 
  "small_buildings" : [ 
    {
      "description" : "basic description",
      "name" : "basic item",
      "income" : 500,
      "startprice" : 30000,
      "id" : 1
    }
    ]
}
```

The code below loops for each file, then loops for each category but the third loop that tries to loop for each building (as in the line "for (var e in econvar.category){") counts from 0-15 and doesn't find a match to the id.

"econvar" marks the file location of the json table.

```
        files.forEach(function (file) {
        let jsonArr = require("C:/discordbot/econdata/" + (file)) // get the initial file
        jsonArr.forEach(function(i){    // for each number in the array of the economy data file
            console.log("got to 2 " + i)
            for(var category in econvar) { // checks for each category in the economy.json file for a match
                console.log("got to 3 " + category)
                for (var e in econvar.category){ // checks each building in the category for a match
                    console.log("got to 4 " + e)
                    if (e.id == i) {
                        console.log("got to 5 " + e.income)
                        total += e.income;
                        channel.send("totalcount: " + total)
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

I've tried changing the variable e, the variable econvar.category and different loop techniques but I either get "got to 4 undefined", "got to 4 (then 0-15 on each line)", or an error.

Thank you. I hope it is not too specific to understand.

Comment: I'd like to add i'm a beginner, if it wasn't obvious. I've been coding JavaScript for a couple months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last for loop you should write:

```
 for (var e in category){ // checks each building in the category for a match
    ...
 }
```

Comment: This brings me slightly closer. I've tried this and it brings me to "got to 4 (then counting 0-15)" but clearly seems like it isn't looping for something in the Json file but for each letter in the category name, which is not good because I'm trying to loop it for every variable in the actual category. Thank you.

Comment: could you provide a complete example of your json data?

Comment: My entire JSON can be found here. https://hastebin.com/exocotoguy.json however, I found a solution to this problem by separating the category loops into individual processes because the amount of categories likely will not change often.